# How to get image from any website with url

Tags: php

I need to get image url only from any webpage with php nothing else.how can i get image url please help.

I have try `file_get_contents(url);` but its not usefull for me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried anything? Can you give an example for you problem? In the current state your question is much too broad to be answered. Try to be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$url="http://example.com";
$html = file_get_contents($url);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($html);
$tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
echo $tag->getAttribute('src');
}
```

Check this code its working for me.